# Issues With Testing On Device & Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having an issue testing my apps on my device and simulator ever since I upgraded to Xcode 8.

Whenever I try and use the simulator on my Mac, it says it cannot find a connection or "DTS, cannot bless the connection". So I plugged in my phone into my Mac to test instead and it seems to cut off half of my app, most importantly my toolbar with buttons. All of my constraints are good in storyboard. So I'm not sure why this is happening. What do I do to fix this? Is it a problem with Xcode?

Comment: try to "Reset Content and Settings..." on the simulator

Comment: Did that, it does the same thing.